# Abydos: Dialing sequence done before?

Tags: stargate

Hold on, so Daniel found the seventh glyph, right? So, why did they do chevron 1-6 like they already tried before. I saw that they knew what they were doing, so why is the seventh chevron a mystery? Did they dial Abydos with all of the glyphs and succeeded or Daniel just told them the way to Abydos, using the Orion as an example.

Comment: P.S Is the Gate destination on the cover stones?

Comment: P.P.S please get a picture of the cover stones for me